# Monopoly Deal - Can you switch your cards after charging rent on them?

Tags: monopoly-deal

If you have one property and another wild card, can you put them together as a set and charge rent on them, and then place the wild card separately, all on your turn? (to save your set from a deal breaker card)

Answer (score 10):

The original rules state that

> [y]ou can move a wild card around between sets on any turn. This does **NOT** count as one of the 3 cards you can play per turn (as it's already on the table).

and

> [i]f you replace a wild card with a property card of the right colour and can't use it as part of another set leave it in your property area - you might need it later!

The rules appear to presume that all properties of the same colour are always placed together.

The first rule allows you to move the wild card (double or rainbow) between two sets, presumably only if in legal positions.

The second implies that if you *can* put a wild card into a set, you *must* put it into a set.

While you can move a wild card out of a complete set to an incomplete set, you cannot move the wild card from any set to be alone.

Comment: Great answer. This was my understanding too. If you have another incomplete set that stays incomplete if you add the wildcard, then you can do what you suggest and your entire move would be valid

Comment: I agree that moving a (rainbow) wild into its own pile doesn't seem legal, but I'm not convinced that's true for 2-color wilds. For example, if I have Boardwalk plus a B/G wild, can't I flip it to blue to charge full rent, then flip it to Green to leave a single Green and single Blue to end the turn?

Comment: If you're not putting it into another set, you're not moving it between sets so you can't separate it off, and if you had a single blue, you can use it as part of another set so you need to put them together. The quoted section above seems pretty clear that wilds are wilds and have the same rules, the only difference between any particular wilds is what colours they can join. @BradC